# On the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \Bigg( \frac{3 + nx}{2n + x} \Bigg)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am studying the series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \Bigg( \frac{3 + nx}{2n + x} \Bigg)^n$$

In particular I am looking at uniform convergence, and have found through the root test that the series converges uniformly in any interval of the type $[0,a]$ with $a < 2$.

But I don't know how to proceed for uniform convergence with $x < 0$? Anybody want to help me out?

Comment: Notice that the series doesn't make sense for a lot of $x < 0$.

Comment: you can't prove uniform convergence for x<0 pick x=-2 for example for n=1 your dividing by 0 for n =2 you get a positive number. in fact for all values of x<0 there exists an n that will give you a positive number and an n that gives you a negative number at some point in the series.

Comment: try setting up an argument on when -2<x<0 and when -2>x where your arguing on the fact of when n is even and when n is odd based on whether the inside is positive or negative will give you two cases.